# Homework - Possible O(n) solution for largest increasing subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I receive a homework like this, but the best solution I have found is still O(nlogn), I would like to ask if it is possible.

[image]

I have asked the lecturer and he says that it is possible, I would like to ask if he is bluffing or just having some kind of final fantasy.

Comment: Describe your `best solution` and/or show crucial parts of it, and argue how this is `O(nlogn)` (and no better). Think about techniques you have been shown/applying, especially recently, and how they might apply to _largest increasing subsequence_. Put in words the obstacles keeping your approaches from needing a constant number of operations per additional number. Meet one or more of your fellow students and exchange ideas - there is more to communication than staring at screens, fingering them or hacking at keys.

Comment: Case closed, the professor misunderstands longest increasing subsequence